# Shelah's proof that proper forcing preserves P-points

Tags: set-theory, forcing, ultrafilters

In Proper and Improper forcing, VI.5; Claim 5.1 part 1 is the following:

If $F$ is a P-point in $V$, $P$ is a proper forcing notion and 
$\Vdash_P `` F$ generates an ultrafilter"
Then the ultrafilter generated by $F$ is a P-point in $V^P$.

The proof starts like this: let $p\Vdash \{\tilde A_n : n<\omega\}$ be such that $p\Vdash \tilde A_n\in F$.

**By properness, for some $q\geq p$ and $A_{n,m}\in F$ for $n,m<\omega$ we have $q\Vdash \tilde A_n\in\{A_{n,m} : m <\omega\}$**

To finish the proof, he uses that $F$ is a P-point in V, and finds an almost-subset of all the $A_{n,m}$.

My question is how is the bolded statement true?  <strike>It appears (since each $A_{n,m}\in V$) that it would follow that P cannot add any subsets of $\omega$, which is clearly not true.</strike>  What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Thanks Mohammad Golshani for the comment.  I now believe that the bolded statement can be true.  But how do we get $q$ (and the collection of $A_{n,m}$)?  Another question is once we have $q$, why is $q$ in $G$?  Is the collection of such $q$ dense below $p$?

Comment: Each $\dot{A}_n$ is forced to be in $F$ hence in $V$, so there is no problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In more details:  Let $N$ be a countable elementary submodel of some sufficiently large $H(\chi)$ containing $p$, $P$, $F$, and the sequence of names $\{\dot A_n:n<\omega\}$.  Then the countable set $N\cap F$ works for the collection of $A_{n, m}$, and any $(N,P)$-generic extension of $p$ will work for $q$.